# DevExpress wpf GridControl сумма по двум колонкам

Tags: wpf, devexpress

В GridControl от DevExpress под WPF можно задать для столбца сумму, которая будет выводиться внизу. А как можно туда вывести не просто сумму, а сумму умножить на значение из другого столбца? Например, есть 2 столбца: количество, цена; для столбца "цена" нужно вывести (сумму * количество). Знаю, что надо обрабатывать событие "CustomSummary", а как именно?

```
<dxg:GridControl.TotalSummary>
   <dxg:GridSummaryItem FieldName="ItemsPrice" SummaryType="Custom"/>               
</dxg:GridControl.TotalSummary>

void GridControl_CustomSummary(object sender, DevExpress.Data.CustomSummaryEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.IsTotalSummary)
    {
        GridSummaryItem item = ((GridSummaryItem)e.Item);
        if (item.FieldName == "ItemsPrice" && item.SummaryType == SummaryItemType.Custom)
        {
            e.TotalValue = ??? 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Согласно [документации](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument6129), подсчет суммы производится в три этапа. Текущий этап определяется проверкой не равно ли свойство [CustomSummaryEventArgs.SummaryProcess](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/DevExpressDataCustomSummaryEventArgs_SummaryProcesstopic) одному из следующих значений: **Start** (инициализация), **Calculate** (подсчет), или **Finalize** (завершение).

**Инициализация**

На этом этапе событие [CustomSummary](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfGridGridControl_CustomSummarytopic) поднимается один раз для каждого айтема у которого [SummaryType](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfGridSummaryItemBase_SummaryTypetopic) задан как **Custom**. Этот этап предназначен для обнуления счетчиков - переменных, объявленных вне метода-обработчика события.

**Подсчет**

На этом этапе производится обход каждой строки, с подниманием события [CustomSummary](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfGridGridControl_CustomSummarytopic). Нужно посчитать значение, которая эта строка добавляет к общей сумме, и соответствующим образом изменить вышеупомянутую переменную-аккумулятор. На этом этапе необходим доступ к данным текущей строки. Он осуществляется через следующие переменные:

[CustomSummaryEventArgs.FieldValue](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/DevExpressDataCustomSummaryEventArgs_FieldValuetopic) - дает значение из колонки, к которой привязан текущий айтемы.

[CustomSummaryEventArgs.Row](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/DevExpressDataCustomSummaryEventArgs_Rowtopic) - дает доступ ко всему объекту, который представляет строка в гриде.

**Завершение**

На этом этапе событие [CustomSummary](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfGridGridControl_CustomSummarytopic) поднимается один раз для каждого айтема у которого [SummaryType](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfGridSummaryItemBase_SummaryTypetopic) задан как **Custom**. Накопленную сумму из переменной-аккумулятора переносят в свойство [CustomSummaryEventArgs.TotalValue](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/DevExpressDataCustomSummaryEventArgs_TotalValuetopic).

```
void grid_CustomSummary(object sender, CustomSummaryEventArgs e) {
    var summaryItem = (GridSummaryItem)e.Item;
    switch (e.SummaryProcess) {
        case CustomSummaryProcess.Start:
            if (summaryItem.FieldName == "UnitPrice")
                InitializeTotalPrice();
            break;
        case CustomSummaryProcess.Calculate:
            if (summaryItem.FieldName == "UnitPrice")
                CalculateTotalPrice((Order)e.Row);
            break;
        case CustomSummaryProcess.Finalize:
                if (summaryItem.FieldName == "UnitPrice")
                    e.TotalValue = GetTotalPrice();
            break;
    }
}

int totalPrice;
void InitializeTotalprice() {
    totalPrice = 0;
}

void CalculateTotalPrice(Order order) {
    totalprice += order.Amount * order.UnitPrice;
}

int GetTotalPrice() {
    return totalPrice;
}
```